# Udyr: Does CDR affect the global cooldown of switching stances?

Tags: league-of-legends

> Udyr uses the stance mechanic. His abilities all have a persistent effect which remain until he activates another ability. Each ability also has a temporary activation effect that occurs upon being cast; the temporary effect of each stance persists for its full duration even if Udyr changes stance again. Switching stances sets off a 2 second global cooldown.

[Udyr Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Udyr)

Does cooldown reduction affect this global cooldown?

Comment: short answer is no

Comment: I expected that, but why does Trick2G have CDR runes and masteries for Udyr?

Comment: exactly the answer said. basically i really doesn't affect the global cooldown of 2 secs, but it will still affect how many times you can switch to a particular stance. i mean, udyr is one of the heroes that really stand out when "adjusting" to a moment, so cdr's are useful to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Global Cooldown is not affected by CDR** however usually a bit of CDR can be really useful on Udyr.

The main reason behind this is the stance switching. You can for example use your Q and then quickly switch to Phoenix stance. Like this you can attack faster and thus proc your Phoenix passive faster and also for a longer time or at least more sustained. There are of course also diffenent combos like Q->E for high er sustain. The more CDR you have the longer you are able to keep the Attackspeed from Q on the Turtle passive, the higher your sustain will be obviously.

Generally you should buy CDR but it shouldn't be your highest priority stat. Defensive stats or Attackspeed are more important for example. Your goal should be between 20 and 30% CDR since this allows you to keep a good uptime in a 2 Spell Rotation while not wasting too much money and slots on useless CDR items.

Comment: but since you have 6 second cooldown on a certain stance it should be possible to get a perfect rotation of 3 stances without having CDR. or am I missing something here? the stance switching is not getting quicker with CDR.

Comment: @PhilippSander Well you'd need at least 16.666% CDR to get a "smooth" rotation. However there is no perfect rotation simply because the playstyle and ability usage are situational. You can safely say that It's usually a good Idea to start with a stun when ganking for example.

Comment: could you give a detailed explenation why you need this amount of CDR for a smooth rotation?

Comment: @PhilippSander because all passive effects last for exactly 5 seconds :P

Comment: ok i see it that way: Q (2sec) R/W(2sec) W/E(2sec). since the abilities have no casttime. CDR can not make this rotation fast in anyway. however i get it when you talk about 2 stance rotations Q (2sec) R/W(2sec).

Comment: Oh wait a second I completely screwed up... ignore everything. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17172/discussion-between-jutschge-and-philipp-sander).